# making the cull function work on dask graph

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, dask

I want to use the cull optimization function on a dask graph.

Here is the code of my use case:

```
input_array = get_dask_array_from_hdf5(input_array, '/data', logic_cs=(770, 605, 700))
# input array is a dask array
subarray = input_array[:1540, :520: 210]
subarray = subarray + 25
d = subarray.dask.dicts

from dask.optimization import cull
dsk1, dependencies = cull(d, ['add-7c83a918eb5b1b9847698e0d800caf0c'])
```

As you can see above, I just want to add some value to part of the array (I loaded the array using a custom function which uses from_hdf5 in background).

My task graph then contains some "getitem" tasks that I dont need, that is why I want to use the cull function to remove them.

But when I use:

```
cull(d, ['add-7c83a918eb5b1b9847698e0d800caf0c'])
```

It cuts everything but the "add" task. I would like to keep the useful "getitems" tasks as well because the add function applies on those "getitem"s.

Inside this "add" task is a "blockwise function" and there is no mention of the getitems on which to apply the blockwise function, therefore I think this is why the cull function removes everything but the add task.

However, I dont know how to proceed to change the blockwise function in order to add the useful getitems as arguments of the blockwise function.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask array culls unneeded nodes of your graph by default.  You should not have to use internal optimization functions manually.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am not sure to understand what you mean by that. In the documentation it is said that we can use cull or inline etc. We are not supposed to use it ? Finally, I found another way to do what I wanted, by using high level graphs features.

Comment: Yes, you can use those functions if you are manipulating dask graphs manually.  Most people don't do this.  Most people use Dask APIs like dask array/dataframe/delayed/futures, which do this for you automatically.